# GORM access list index of hasMany association

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My application has domain classes which have the same logical relation as photo albums and individual photographs. Using a `List` for the `hasMany` association should support backwards and forward movement within individual albums, without having to explicitly manage a position field or previous / next pointers.

For example:

```
class Album {
    static hasMany = [photos: Photo]
    List photos // Generates column `album_idx` in table for Photo.
    Integer size // Memoized.
}

class Photo {
    static belongsTo = [album: Album]
    static hasOne = [content: PhotoData] // PhotoData has byte[] field for data
}

class Controller {
    def prev() {
        def prevIdx = idx==0 ? album.size - 1 : idx -1 // etc.
    }
}
```

Can I access the value of the `_idx` without a native SQL query?

I've tried `photo.album.photos.indexOf(photo)`, but `indexOf` returns `-1` because the loading is apparently too lazy for `indexOf`, though in general I *do* want lazy loading. I blame lazy loading because in the debugger list items are randomly populated and I suspect those that are were simply cached previously. It's possible I'm misunderstanding GORM's behavior here.

In any event `photo.album.photos.indexOf(photo)` is uglier and (probably) slower than an immediate field access. Ideally I could define a mapping between the generated `_idx` column and a field in `Photo`, to allow access using `photo.albumIdx`.

Comment: What error do you get if you do `b.a.bees.indexOf(b)`? Why do you seek the index?

Comment: @dmahapatro I changed the whole question around a bit, hopefully it's more explicit / clear now. Thanks for the previous edits btw.

Comment: I needed to get at that index recently - ended up putting an index column explicitly. Wasn't too much work to manage it at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [indexColumn](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html) in combination with [updateable](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/updateable.html) and [insertable](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/insertable.html) mappings, you can have collection items (e.g. your Photos) index aware. For example:

```
class Album {
    static hasMany = [photos: Photo]
    List photos // Generates column `album_idx` in table for Photo.
    Integer size // Memoized.

    static mapping = {
      photos indexColumn: [name: "position", type: Integer]
    }
}

class Photo {
    Integer position

    static belongsTo = [album: Album]
    static hasOne = [content: PhotoData] // PhotoData has byte[] field for data

    static mapping = {
      position updateable: false, insertable: false
    }
}
```

`photo.position` will now give you this photo's index (NOTE: by default list order is 0 based)

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was possible but didn't know how to set up the mapping properly.