# Grails- how to get part of the values in set collection?

Tags: grails, collections, grails-services

I have a domain which call party and has many invitees.
party.invitees give me a the set collection of the invitees.
I want to get only some of the invitees so I try do do the followinf in my service.

```
partInvitees= event?.invitees?.findAll{[offset: 3,max: 8]}
```

It doesn't give the correct result. It gives me all the invitees instead only the specific I have asked.

Comment: You need to put filter condition in the findAll closure.

Comment: @Abs- how should I add it?

Answer (score 0):

The `findAll` method you are invoking in there is not from GORM, but from [Groovy Collections](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll%28%29). So even if you paginate it (which is not possible directly in Groovy, AFAIK), you'll be bringing the whole collection into memory. If you don't mind, just do:

`event?.invitees[offset..(offset-1)+max]`

If the collection is too big and you don't want to bring it to memory, you can also query the `Invitee` directly:

`Invitee.findAllByEvent(event, [offset: 3,max: 8])`

But **be aware that the order won't be necessarily the same**, since Gorms' `findAllBy` doesn't know about the collection index (I'm assuming `invitees` is a list). You can make the collection index-aware, but [it's a bit tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524281/gorm-access-list-index-of-hasmany-association).

Comment: I am not sure this statement is accurate: "The `findAll` method you are invoking in there is not from GORM...". The **Description** section in the [findAll method in the Grails Docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html) says: "The findAll method allows querying with Hibernate's query language HQL and querying by example...". So, if running under the realm of Grails, then those `find*` methods do get elevated to becoming GORM citizens I believe.

Comment: This is only true for methods invoked against a domain class as if they were static AFAIK. IntelliJ Idea seems to agree - if I try to get to the definition of a findAllBy that is invoked against a collection, it tells me "DefaultGroovyMethods". Also, the documentation doesn't make sense for a property whose type is a collection - what would you expect this to do: event?.invitees.findAll("from ...")?

Comment: (my comment give the impression that I'm not sure, but I'm just ellaborating it more to present some arguments instead of saying "no, it's not"... but I'm actually sure it is like that :)

Comment: For the statement `event?.invitees.findAll("from ...")`, I expect the answer to depend on the type of object `event` is; if `event` is a grails domain object, then it's GORMly treated, right?

Comment: No, again, invitees is a collection, is not a domain class instance. But even if it was a domain class instance, it wouldn't be GORM's find - that's only the case when you are using the method in the class, not in an instance. Check the documentation link you posted, all the invokations are against a class, not an instance. But I understand you don't want to blidnly trust me, so if you have a Grails project at hand give it a go yourself.

Comment: Will have to study this deeply now. If `Event` is a domain class, then so would `Invitee` be through the `hasMany` relationship (unless it's declared `transient`) - leading me to believe that it's GORM all over; but you are saying "even if it was a domain class instance..." - confused now and will have to investigate :-)

Comment: Just to clarify: `Event` and `Invitee` are domain classes, yes. But the property `invitees` inside `Event` is of type `Set` or `List`. Yes, the `hasMany` helps Gorm knowing with which domain class this list should be associated. But you can still do `event.invitee = [ invitee1, invitee2 ].each { it.event = event}` and everything will work (is better to use the `addToInvitees` method, sure, but internally is just doing what I wrote). That list is a normal Groovy list. Is not a domain class. Is not a domain class instance. Is just a plain old Groovy list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GORM `list()` method to get the entire collection for a domain class. If you want only a subset of the collection you could use `list()` with some parameters.

If your domain class is named `Invite`, you should use `Invite.list(max: 8, offset: 3, sort: "id", order: "asc")` to get the subset described in your question. Keep in mind that different sort/order params could give you different results.

See the [`list()`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/list.html) or [`listOrderBy()`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/listOrderBy.html) documentation for more information.

If you want `Invites` only for a specific `Event` you should read the Deigote answer.